# How does the java TreeSet explicitly function?

Tags: java, arrays, treeset

1) Can anyone please explain or point me toward a tutorial that will explain and give examples of how the TreeSet accomplishes it's task? More specifically, what is the written out code behind the class that allows it to function?

2) Also, can TS be used to sort an unsorted array of strings?

Thanks so much!

EDIT: For (2), I am attempting to initialize a string String[] names = strings {junk names...} and have them lexicographically sorted. Is TS the correct call to make? Or is there another direction I should look.

Comment: The source code is publicly available. A `TreeSet` is implemented with a `TreeMap` which is implemented as a Red Black tree.

Answer (score 1):

In short TreeSet= `Tree(for ordering) + Set(for avoiding duplicates)`. In java Comparator/Comparable is used to compare two object in treeset

For Details,you need to have look at TreeSet source code . Here is the link [Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java)

Comment: Please find a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

A TreeSet is backed by a TreeMap, which is a red-black tree -http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap

In treeset object stored in sorted manner, using compareTo() method.
So you can use this to get sorted array.

Comment: I appreciate the link, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm a little confused on what your second statement means though, could you elaborate? I just started teaching myself java, are you saying that the compareTo() method can be implemented IN the TS function, or called beforehand?

Comment: I just want to inform that TreeSet use compateTo() implementation to sort the array, don't confuse with it.And yes you can override this method to give ur on implementation. check this for more details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html